# how to display real time record count of PHPexcel using Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

I want to display real-time record count at front end using `PHPexcel` and `Ajax`. I am doing this by creating JSON file and storing data into this. Can I have a better option to show record count in the HTML? It is taking so much time AS the JSON file opening and closing so many times. At the same time, I am requesting this JSON and displaying data on the frontend. I am having this code and sharing you. Please let me know can I have a better option for the same.

**File Name: Index.html**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>jQuery Ajax file upload with percentage progress bar</h3>
            <form id="myform" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select file: </label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="myfile" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--<div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success myprogress" role="progressbar" style="width:0%">0%</div>
                    </div>-->

                    <div class="msg"></div>
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" id="progressbar" role="progressbar" style="width:0%">0%</div>
                    </div>

                    <h2 id="records"></h2>
                    <h2 id="consist"></h2>
                    <h2 id="hsn"></h2>

                </div>

                <input type="button" id="btn" class="btn-success" value="Upload" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
      $(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                $('.myprogress').css('width', '0');
                $('.msg').text('');
                var filename = $('#filename').val();
                var myfile = $('#myfile').val();
                if (filename == '' || myfile == '') {
                    alert('Please enter file name and select file');
                    return;
                }
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('myfile', $('#myfile')[0].files[0]);
                formData.append('filename', filename);
                $('#btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
               // $('.msg').text('Uploading in progress...');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'uploadscript.php',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    /*
                    xhr: function () {
                        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();  
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                                $('.myprogress').text(percentComplete + '%');
                                $('.myprogress').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                            }
                        }, false);
                        return xhr;
                    },*/
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        var myData = JSON.parse(data);
                        console.log(myData.records.length);
                        $('#records').text("Records Found : " + myData.records.length).show();
                        $('#consist').text("Consistency : " + (myData.records.length - myData.notConsist.length)).show();
                        //$('.msg').text(data);
                        $('.msg').html(`<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> Upload successfully!</div>`);
                        $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $('.progress').hide();
                    }
                });   
                t = setTimeout("updateStatus()", 3000);
            });
        });

        function updateStatus(){ 
          $.getJSON('upload/my.json', function(data){      
                               var items = []; 

                               pbvalue = 0; 
                               var notExistHSN = 0;
                               var consistency = 0;
                               var notConsist = 0;
                               if(data){ 

                                    var total = data['total']; 

                                    var current = data['current'];  




                                    console.log(current);

                                    var pbvalue = Math.floor((current / total) * 100);  

                                    if(pbvalue>0){   

                                    $('#progressbar').text(pbvalue + '%');
                                    $('#progressbar').css('width', pbvalue + '%');
                                        //console.log(pbvalue);  
                                    }  
                                    $('#records').text("Records Found : " + current).show();


                                }  
                                if(pbvalue < 100){  

                                   t = setTimeout("updateStatus()", 3000);  

                                }  
          }).fail(function() {t = setTimeout("updateStatus()", 3000)});  
        } 
    </script>
```

**File Name : uploadscript.php**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$target_dir = 'upload/';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);


$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

require('Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once "Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
$path = $target_file;
$fileObj = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load( $path );
$sheetObj = $fileObj->getActiveSheet();


$startFrom = 1; //default value is 1
$limit =null;
$header=array();
foreach( $sheetObj->getRowIterator($startFrom, $limit) as $row ){

foreach( $row->getCellIterator() as $cell ){
    $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue(); 
    array_push($header,$value);
}
break;
}

$highestRow = $sheetObj->getHighestRow();

$arr = array('total'=>($highestRow-1), 'current'=>'0', 'notConsist'=>'0', 
'hsn'=>'0');

file_put_contents("upload/my.json",json_encode($arr));

$startFrom = 2; 
$limit =count($header);
$i=1;
$outp = "";
foreach( $sheetObj->getRowIterator($startFrom, $limit) as $row ){
if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
foreach( $row->getCellIterator() as $key=>$cell){
    // get all total count
    $arr['current'] = "$i"; 
    file_put_contents("upload/my.json",json_encode($arr));
    $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
    if($key==0){$outp .= '{"'.$header[$key].'":"'. $value. '",';}
    else
    if($key==($limit-1)){$outp .= '"'.$header[$key].'":"'. $value. '"}';

    }
    else {        
    $outp .= '"'.$header[$key].'":"'. $value. '",';
    }
  }
  $i++;
 }
 $outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
 echo $outp;
```

?>

Comment: why are you opening/closing the file for every bit you write into it? If that's taking the time, as you claim, then don't do it. Wait until the end and then write it all at one go.

Comment: i am using file put content function in php

Comment: So? I can see that, I don't need you to tell me that. And what difference does that make? It doesn't stop you doing what I suggested. Again, if you've identified that as a performance problem, then just call it once with a string containing all your data, instead of once for every data item. Build up a string of all the data, and then at the end of your code make a single call to file_put_contents and pass that string.